# Problems with messagebox in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a jumble word game in python tkinter but I have difficulty trying to create a front window where the user can see the game rules etc. I tried creating a frame so I can display the information of the rules inside but the messagebox keeps popping up when running the code. Is there a way to fix that problem or create a first window that shows the rules which then redirects you to the game ? Also I apologize if some of the words are in french in my code.
Thank you.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from tkinter import messagebox

#Creation de la fenetre
fenetre = Tk()

rep =["python",'virus','while','for','if','label','import','tkinter','random','fenetre','uct','clavier','hertz','print','global']
mots=["ohtnpy",'visur','lehiw','rfo','fi','eblal','ripotm','kntiert','draomn','nefetre','tcu','vrilcea','heztr','tnrip','oabgll']

lettre =random.randrange(0,len(mots),1)
#La variable du score
a=0
#Le nombre de fois joué
j=0
#Variable qui calcule le score
s = ""

#L'affichage du score
lbl_score= Label(fenetre)

def mélanger():
  global mots, rep, lettre
  lettres =random.randrange(0,len(mots),1)
  label.config(text = mots[lettres])
  E1.delete(0, END)

def default():
  global mots,rep,lettre
  label.config(text = mots[lettre])

def vérif_rep():
  global mots, rep,lettre, a, j, s, lbl_score
  j=int(j)+1
  trouve = E1.get() #obtenir la reponse
  if trouve == rep[lettre]: #Trouve si la réponse est juste ou non
      messagebox.showinfo("Bravo", "C'est la bonne reponse!!")
      a = int(a)+1
  else:
      messagebox.showerror("Oops", "C'est pas la bonne réponse.")
  s = 'Score :' + str(a) + '/' + str(j)
  lbl_score.forget()
  lbl_score = Label(fenetre, font=("Verdana", 20), text=s, bg="#800080", fg="#fff", )
  lbl_score.pack(side=LEFT)
  mélanger()

#Affichage de la fenètre
fenetre.geometry("800x500")
fenetre.title("Jeu de mots-melés")
fenetre.configure(background="light pink")

#Création du titre
Label(fenetre,text="Jeu de mots-melés",font = ("Verdana",28),bg = "#000000", fg = "#fff").pack(pady = 5)
label = Label(fenetre,font = ("Verdana",22),bg = "#000000", fg = "#fff")
label.pack(pady = 30,ipady=10,ipadx=10)


obt_rep = StringVar()

#Boite d'entrée
E1 = Entry(fenetre,font = ("Verdana",20),textvariable = obt_rep,)
E1.pack(ipady=5,ipadx=5)

#Les boutons du code
Button(fenetre,text = "Vérifier",font = ("Comic sans ms",20),width = 10,bg="#333945",fg="#45CE30",relief = GROOVE,command = vérif_rep(),).pack(pady = 40)
Button(fenetre,text = "Mélanger",font = ("Comic sans ms",20),width = 10,bg="#777E8B",fg="#E1DA00",relief = GROOVE,command = mélanger()).pack()


C3 = Frame(fenetre, relief='groove', bd=10)
C3.place(x=700, y=300, width=500, height=500)



default()

fenetre.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to create two windows from the beginning or creating a windows with buttons. You can try what fits better for your game and rules.

```
from tkinter import *

def openNewWindow():
    newWindow = Toplevel(root)
    newWindow.title("New Window")
    newWindow.geometry("300x300")
    newWindowLabel = Label(newWindow, text='openNewWindow', font=('Helvetica', 16, 'bold')).place(x=50,y=50)
        
def openAnotherWindow():
    otherWindow = Toplevel(root)
    otherWindow.title("New Window")
    otherWindow.geometry("300x300")
    anotherWindowLabel = Label(otherWindow, text='openanotherWindow', font=('Helvetica', 16, 'bold')).place(x=50,y=50)

root = Tk()
root.title("Example tkinter windows")
root.geometry("300x350")
openNewWindow()

btn1 = Button(root,text="openNewWindow",command=openNewWindow)
btn1.place(x=100,y=100)

btn2 = Button(root,text="anotherWindow",command=openAnotherWindow)
btn2.place(x=100,y=200)

root.mainloop()
```